# What is the purpose of python.exe in the pypy binary distribution?

Tags: python, pypy

When run, it fails with

```
'import site' failed
debug: OperationError:
debug:  operror-type: ModuleNotFoundError
debug:  operror-value: No module named '_pypy_generic_alias'
```

pypy.exe, python3.exe and all other python-ish exes in the directory work identically, only python.exe fails. Why? Is it somehow special? How are you supposed to set up your environment to use it and why?

Comment: It works for me: I downloaded from https://downloads.python.org/pypy/, unzipped it, and ran the python.exe there. What exactly did you do?